# trying to update values in a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Currently I am having issues with updating values in a SQL Server database.

I am working on a project that stores students names, dates of birth and genders in a database and is able to be edited and updated via windows forms. Browsing the data so far works fine, however when a value is changed on the form and the update button is clicked the program crashes with a

> NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

error and I am currently at a loss as to what is causing it.

Currently I have a `DBConnector` class which opens up the connection to the database and the dataset and passes it to the windows form which contains textboxes to show the values and navigational buttons to browse the data. (Below is the code for both the class and the windows form, I hope that can explain things better than I have).

The `DBConnector.cs` class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace StudentRecords
{
    public class DBConnector
    {
        //Properties
        //connection object
        private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Conn;

        //dataset object
        private StudentsDataSet Ds1;
        //dataadapter object
        private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter Da;

        //constructors
        public DBConnector()
        {
            //call initialisation
            init();
        }

        //Methods
        //initialisation method
        public void init()
        {
            //create the memory space for the connection object
            Conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            //create the memory space for the dataset
            Ds1 = new StudentsDataSet();

            //set the connection string to the location of our database file
            Conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Students.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

            //open the conenction
            Conn.Open();

            //create a query to get all the records from the table
            string query = "SELECT * from Studentstbl";
            //create the data adapter for the database
            Da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(query, Conn);
            //use it to fill the dataset as the first parameter the second is a name for the table we use later on
            Da.Fill(Ds1, "Students");


            //close the connection
            Conn.Close();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Database connection Open", "Success");
        }

        public StudentsDataSet DBDataSet
        {
            get
            {
                return Ds1;
            }
        }

        //update method

        public void UpdateDB(DataSet ds, string table)
        {
            //create a command builder to reconnect to the database
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
            //set the comamnd builder to be our existing dataadapter
            cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(Da);
            Da.Update(ds, table);
        }
    }
}
```

The `studentdetails.cs` Windows Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StudentRecords
{
    public partial class studentdetails : Form
    {
        DataSet StudentDataSet;
        //set variables for limit
        int Limit = 0;
        int current = 0;

        public studentdetails()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public studentdetails(DataSet ds)
            : this()
        {
            StudentDataSet = ds;
            //set the limit of records we can navigate
            Limit = StudentDataSet.Tables["Students"].Rows.Count;

            NavigateRecords();
        }

       public studentdetails(DBConnector db) : this()
       { }

        public studentdetails(DBConnector db, int sRow) : this(db)
        {
            current = sRow;
            NavigateRecords();
            //turn on editing
            plEdit.Visible = true;
            //set our local dataset object to point to the passed in one
            DBConnection = db;
            StudentDataSet = db.DBDataSet;
            Limit = StudentDataSet.Tables["Students"].Rows.Count;
            NavigateRecords();
        }

        //navigate records function to move through the records
        public void NavigateRecords()
        {   //create a datarow object and set it to be the first row in the dataset
            DataRow dRow = StudentDataSet.Tables["Students"].Rows[current];
            //set the form text to add the current record number
            this.Text += " for record " + dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
            //fill the text boxes with the database values
            txtFirstName.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
            txtMiddleName.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
            txtLastName.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
            txtDOB.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
            txtgender.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();
        }

        //update the label for the dtatbase
        private void UpdateCount()
        {
            txtCount.Text = (current + 1).ToString() + " of " + Limit.ToString();
        }

        private void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (current != Limit - 1)
            {
                current++;
                NavigateRecords();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Last Record", "Information", 0, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void btn_prev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (current > 0)
            {
                current--;
                NavigateRecords();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("First Record", "Information", 0, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void btn_Last_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (current != Limit - 1)
            {
                current = Limit - 1;
                NavigateRecords();
            }
        }

        private void btn_first_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (current != 0)
            {
                current = 0;
                NavigateRecords();
            }
        }

        public DBConnector DBConnection { get; set; }

        private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                //create a new datarow 
                DataRow dRow = StudentDataSet.Tables["Students"].NewRow();

                //set the data to be the values from the text boxes
                dRow[1] = txtFirstName.Text;
                dRow[2] = txtMiddleName.Text;
                dRow[3] = txtLastName.Text;
                dRow[4] = txtDOB.Text;
                dRow[5] = txtgender.Text;


                //add the row to our dataset
                StudentDataSet.Tables["Studentstbl"].Rows.Add(dRow);

                //increase the limit as we have a new record
                Limit++;
                //move to the newly entered Student
                current = Limit - 1;
                DBConnection.UpdateDB(StudentDataSet, "Students");
                MessageBox.Show("Record Saved", "Information", 0, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                NavigateRecords();
            }



        }

        private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {   //get the current row
                DataRow dRow = StudentDataSet.Tables["Students"].Rows[current];
                //set the dataset values to those in the textboxes
                dRow[1] = txtFirstName.Text;
                dRow[2] = txtMiddleName.Text;
                dRow[3] = txtLastName.Text;
                dRow[4] = txtDOB.Text;
                dRow[5] = txtgender.Text;

                //call the update method in our DB connector class
                DBConnection.UpdateDB(StudentDataSet, "Students");
                //display a message box
                MessageBox.Show("Record updated", "Information", 0, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                NavigateRecords();
            }

        }






    }
}
```

The database is called `Students.mdf` and the table is called `Studentstbl`, the error is thrown on line:

```
DBConnection.UpdateDB(StudentDataSet, "Students");
```

I know its probably something stupid I have missed out but I am fairly new with C# coding so forgive me if this is the case :)

Edit: I should also point out that `studentdetails` is a secondary form with the main form simply containing a button which opens that form in it, it simple contains the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Coursework3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DBConnector Students;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //intansiate the object in memory
            Students = new DBConnector();
        }

        private void btnstudentdetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new studentdetails(Students.DBDataSet).ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're new, learn to use a debugger... I bet you will find the problem yourself if you can track the exception to the specific line of code ;)

Comment: Agree, run this in debug mode and you should end up right at the offending line of code that is causing your null reference exception.  This is an object that is not initialized with a value but attempt is being made to access it in some manner -- calling a function, properties, etc.  If you are still having trouble, post leave a comment with the offending line from tracking it down via debug.

Comment: Your `DBConnection` is null, almost certainly because it only ever gets set in one of your three constructors.  I'm guessing that that's not the one that you are calling.

Comment: `NullReferenceExceptions` are some of the most common (and easiest to fix) exceptions in the .NET stack.  My question to you is, `DBConnection.UpdateDB(StudentDataSet, "Students");` if the exception is being thrown on this line, which object is `null`?  A breakpoint here might tell you...